# Blazor - Equivalent to Vue Watch for a Parameter

Tags: vue.js, blazor

Coming from a VueJS background to Blazor, I can't find an equivalent to the Vue watcher in Blazor.

To elaborate, in Vue, one could watch for changes on a certain property, for example:

```
watch: {
   somethingId(newValue) {
      // Do something, this actually watches the somethingId for change and trigger this function
   }
}
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent to Blazor, I tried to achieve that using a custom property's getter/setter but this does not work in all cases (it is actually more similar to computed properties in vue and not a watch).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In C# you can implement INotifyProperyChanged.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1 Is this what your after?

Comment: How can I implement that on a parameter within a Blazor component?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki you probably don't need to. Blazor already notices when the values of fields and parameters change. What are you trying to do? Post the actual *Blazor* code. Or actual *Vue* code that shows what you want to do `// Do something, this actually watches` that doesn't explain anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not available in Blazor as per the team on the [ASP.NET Github Repository](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26958#issuecomment-709905589).

I ended up implementing a **state container** (a similar concept to Vuex in VueJS) to store the common values that I'm looking to observe (instead of passing them as `Parameters`) and throwing events upon their changes. This is documented in [ASP.NET Core Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service).

Let's say we need to watch/observe the changes to `somethingId`, similar to the example above:

1. Create a `SomethingStateContainer` class with the following:

```
public class SomethingStateContainer
{
    public event Action<int> OnSomethingIdChanged; // Or any type, here SomethingId is an int

    private int _somethingId = 0;
    public int SomethingId {
        get => _somethingId;
        set {
            _somethingId = value;
            OnSomethingIdChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This service is then added as a singleton within the `Program.cs` (if using Blazor WebAssembly):

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomethingStateContainer>();
```

2. Each component looking to listen on changes done over this variable can do so as follows:

- Inject the `SomethingStateContainer` within the Blazor component:

```
@inject SomethingStateContainer SomethingStateContainer
```

- Add an event listener (and dispose it when done):

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    SomethingStateContainer.OnSomethingIdChanged += YourCallbackFunction;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    SomethingStateContainer.OnSomethingIdChanged -= YourCallbackFunction;
}
```

Where the `YourCallbackFunction` is the function that you wish to execute (In this case it takes an `int` as an input):

```
private void YourCallbackFunction(int id)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why do that? Blazor already watches for changes to fields and parameters in a component. In the `Fetch` sample you see that Blazor notices that `forecasts` has changed and redraws the UI. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is used for changes *inside* a model, in WPF and WinForms. BUT in React and Vue, where components are typically small and *aren't* supposed to watch for deep changes anyway, this isn't needed

Comment: Event callbacks can be used to notify parent components when changes occur too, and have the parents update their state, leading to a redraw. Again, that's how eg React works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right, when binding to the parameter, the UI will update automatically. But in my particular scenario, I need to call a certain action to execute (an API call) when this parameter changes this is why I needed to resort to this. In addition, this particular parameter is used in multiple components across the page so this also spares me from passing it to all components manually.

Comment: In that case you can use an EventCallback. Blazor is closer to how React works - state changes flow downwards and parents are notified through callbacks. You can use a single method to handle events from multiple components. Blazor knows that an EventCallback will change state though, so there's no need to call `StateHasChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Use OnParametersSet(),this event happen after OnInitialzed.

[image]

```js
@code{
  [Parameter] public int UserId{get;set;}
  private int _userId;

  protected overrid void OnParametersSet(){
    if(_userId!=UserId){
      _userId=UserId;
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```